# Add image to custom folder in Xamarin Android Resources

Tags: xaml, xamarin.android

All the tutorials say that the images should be added to the Resources/drawable folder in case of Xamarin Android application. And that works absolutely fine. My question - is it possible to create a custom folder inside Resources to better organize the images? It's not very good to have them all in root of drawable folder.

[image: The image presents my structure]

The image is not displayed. When it is straight in the root of drawable, it works fine. Is it possible to have a nonflat image folder structure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**No**, drawable can't have subdirectories. you can't put it.

Comment: Thanks for clearing this up. Too bad, I'd prefer to have images organised.

Answer (score 0):

You Can Add Folder name raw and you will able to access it from Resource.Raw

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).